# 'Unauthorized' when using Cognito User Pool Authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-iot

So I had an API (let's call it API number 1) and one user pool. The API was used for testing purposes. It called a lambda function to update an IOT shadow. Now I used cognito to create a user pool and added some users in it. Then, I created an authorizer for API number 1 with the same user pool and enabled authorization in POST method execution for it. I created a login form so that I could log into cognito user pool and would get an ID token from it. I used that id token in POSTMAN along with Authorization header and the post worked. When I did not provide the id token, I got message: unauthorized as a response. The IOT shadow was updated only when I provided the authorization header and id token which meant everything went smoothly.

Then for testing purpose I created another API (API number 2), I replicated API number 1 entirely, created an authorizer with the same pool, enabled Authorization, logged in, got the id token used it in POSTMAN with Authorization header (the same process) and it didn't work. I kept getting message: unauthorized.

Then I thought maybe the problem was with API number 2 and created API number 3. This time I also created an entirely new user pool. I used that user pool to create an authorizer. The rest, I replicated API number 1 entirely again. I enabled CORS, in POST method execution I added Authorization. I did everything. Still when I tried again with POSTMAN, it didn't work.

So, API number 1 still functions perfectly like it should. API 2 and API 3 do not work despite having the exact same configurations as API 1. 
I really do not know where I am going wrong. I even tried creating separate lambda functions for each API. Even the lambda code is the same (except for the IOT certificates and the IOT shadow URL).

Please, Help!! At this point I think I have tried almost everything and still I don't know whats wrong. One seems to work with the same configuration that the other two have whereas the other two don't. Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: Did you clilck on Deploy API?

Comment: Yes I redeployed the API

Comment: First, test the Id token in the second API's authorizer in the API Gayeway console itself. Does it work? Are you passing the token directly or do you use prefix the word 'Bearer' before it? Try using curl. Postman add/changes headers a lot so using curl may give a different response. Ultimately, it is hard to debug such an issue without seeing the setup. Everything you did looks fine.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. No, I am not adding bearer because that seemed to work for the first api. I tried testing the same token with the second API but it didn't work. I am currently trying things out with curl just so I know the difference in the response messages I get. I will post any results I get. Thanks again.

Comment: Also I noticed something. In the API where things worked out, the response I got when I provided an expired ID token wass {message:"Identity token has expired;"}. However this is not the case with the other two APIs. Even when I provide an expired ID token I still get {message: "unauthorized;"}. It's like the ID token is non-existent to the other two APIs

Comment: SOLVED!!!! The problem seemed to be when I created the authorizers and set token validation as none. It should have been blank and not none. Leaving it blank will automatically produce null, but manually adding null is a different case I see. Thanks for the effort everyone

Comment: It maybe so because setting the field to blank means not matching the token to any regular exp but setting it to none means the token will be matched with "none" and hence not work.